# Is it possible to get a true/false answer as to whether a given document matches a previously defined Elasticsearch query?

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Is it possible to get a true/false answer as to whether a given document matches a previously defined Elasticsearch query?(mainly in java)

Or is it necessary to execute the previously defined query and then check if the document is included in the response set?

Comment: How can ES answer with true or false without executing the query?

Comment: my question is not about whether i have to execute a query or not, but about whether i can get a simple true or false answer. my defined search query might get a million documents as a result and i have to check now if a given document is a subset of the total result.

Or in other words, there is an API that i give a document and a query to and returns true/false?

Comment: No, check if a document exists or not needs to run a query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

elasticsearch has a percolate query ( [documentation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-percolate-query.html) ) that corresponds to your needs.

> The percolate query can be used to match queries stored in an index.
> The percolate query itself contains the document that will be used as
> query to match with the stored queries.

So in your case, you should create a new index to store your request then try to match your document against this request.

Regards